# What format are these coordinates in?

Tags: coordinate-system

This is part of a mathematical challenge which I am solving. In the final deciphered message, I am given coordinates which correspond to some location that I need to check.

Coordinates are: 511716656388765455430016138955706839007890052532, 1622805609316535864254436412730925222158623332074

These are very large numbers and the information obtained is correct. I verified it. Also, I have another set of coordinates similar to these which I need to look up.

I read about different Geographical Coordinate Systems here: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion

However, none of them match it.

Could it be a non standard format of representing coordinates?

Comment: For every location, there are infinitely many (non-standard) spatial reference systems for which these coordinates refer to that respective location. Unless someone can come up with a finite list of reference systems (standard ones, or actually used non-standard ones) for which these are valid coordinates, I doubt this question can be reasonably answered.

Comment: The (admittedly hardly useful) answer to the verbatim question is thus "Yes, it could."

Comment: I had that bookmarked this site and saw your questoin. See if you can figure that out..   https://twcc.fr/#donate

Comment: Can be Lat 5.1171... N, Lon 16.2280... E, but expressed in 10^-47 decimal degrees. Or any other. The question only makes sense if you can decipher between those numbers the angles that represent the latitude (-90, + 90) and the longitude (-180, + 180), maybe in radians, since it is a mathematical challenge (you can even verify if those long numbers represent valid geographic coordinates by subtracting _k_ times 2 _PI_ ). I do not believe that they express metric units, since it would imply a projection system that should be explicit in the question.

Comment: @PROBERT I didn't understand you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: 49 and 48 digit numbers would be incredibly precise coordinates.  If they are some fraction of a 40,000,000 meter earth circumference, the precision would be sub-subatomic.  Could there be another level of decoding to reduce them to something less than 10 digit numbers?

Comment: Would it make sense for the data to be in Poland? Or maybe Yemen?

Comment: I am sorry, @NeonFlash, what I am trying to say here is that you can input the coordinates numbers on that site and see if it comes up to where it is ..  Get it ?